# Ajv keywords and custom error messages

Tags: javascript, ajv

I have written a schema but it does not seem to be validating as I was expecting. I'm assuming there is something wrong with my schema syntax but cannot figure it out. I expect not to see error messages for title or target until fundraiser is complete since they are only required if fundraiser is completed. I've tried many combinations but none of them are working as expected, these two are the closest I've come to what I need.

**Schema attempt one**: shows 4 error messages, 3 required errors and 1 error saying data should match "then" schema.

```
const schema = {
  required: ['fundraiser'],
  if: {
    properties: {
      fundraiser: { type: 'string' },
    },
  },
  then: {
    required: ['title', 'target'],
  },
  errorMessage: {
    required: {
      fundraiser: 'Please select an option',
      title: 'Please enter a title',
      target: 'Please enter a target',
    },
  },
};
```

**Schema attempt two**: shows 2 error messages, 1 required error and 1 error saying data should match "then" schema which is correct but then when I complete fundraiser valid becomes true which is when I expect to then see required errors for title and target. Also no errors have my defined custom error messages.

```
const scema = {
  if: {
    properties: { fundraiser: { minLength: 2 } },
    then: { required: ['title', 'target'] },
  },
  then: { required: ['fundraiser'] },
  errorMessage: {
    required: {
      fundraiser: 'Please select an option',
      title: 'Please enter a title',
      target: 'Please enter a target',
    },
  },
};
```

I am pretty sure that I am doing something wrong with my schema but it is not clear from the documentation how to use if/then in combination with custom error messages using ajv-errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the first schema is that subschema inside “if” is valid, unless fundraiser property is present and not a string. It would probably work as you expect if you add `type: 'object'` to the root schema and move `required` inside “if” subschema.

The problem with the second subschema is that the first “then” that has no  “if” in the same schema object is ignored (unless you are using ajv-keywords that implemented if/then/else somewhat differently from how it is defined in draft-07 of JSON Schema spec) and the subschema inside “if is valid even if fundraiser property is absent and the second “then” can only pass if fundraiser is present.